# login box appears as a drop down down box on clicking a tab in main menu

Tags: theming, users

i want to have the login box displayed on the front page as a dropdown box when login tab in menu is clicked...i have added the tab and now on clicking it takes me to node/user as i have set the path to it...however i want that when menu is clicked a drop down box appears having field to enter the username and password..and then login and forget password etc..can someone help me on this...have searched a lot on this but to no avail...

Comment: are you looking at something like this? http://ajax-register.drupalace.ru/ when you click on login a popup comes up

Comment: hi sir..thanks for the fast reply..i am not looking for something exactly like this...what i am looking for is that when i click a tab (which i have placed in main menu and named as login) a drop down box appears which asks the required fields..however how to do as  ajax-register.drupalace.ru  would also interest me

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/ajax_register that is module used in the link i provided. for the tab structure you can do it using custom js.

Comment: thanks ..i will look into it..what i was looking for is something like: http://imgur.com/bMR5oBK

Comment: http://adaptivethemes.com/twitter-style-login-box-for-drupal this is for drupal 6 but should work for 7 as well

Comment: once again..thanks a lot..you have been a great help for the last few days..thanks and regards